# Aura UtilityBar Components: How to set default component dimensions on the Lightning App Builder and prevent modifying of these values?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute, utility-bar, design-attributes

I am currently developing an Aura component for the UtilityBar and I am having trouble setting default values for the component on the App Manager screen. For an example: I would like to set height and width for the users and also prevent the value from being modified, like this component:

[image]

Notice how the fields are greyed out in the image above, I would like to do the same for my component. Any assistance on how to accomplish this result would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Blake, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. If you already have an aura component started, it can be helpful to [edit] your question and provide that along with anything you may have researched in accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what your screenshot shows as it's a standard component. However, you really shouldn't need to expose the values in that view if the goal is for them to be read-only.

The point of adding a [Design Resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm) to your component bundle is to *expose editable properties* for your component. It's made for customization from the end user. If you just want to have default values, set them within your component and the end user shouldn't need to see them or know about them.

In other words, looking at the provided attributes at your disposable to customize design resources shows there's nothing to make it read-only.

- datasource
- default
- description
- label
- max
- min
- name
- placeholder
- required
- type

As such, you can just set the defaults in your aura component or leverage some custom setting/metadata types if you want to see its values outside the component and have more control over it.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="panelWidth" type="Integer" default="340" />
    <aura:attribute name="panelHeight" type="Integer" defaul="480"/>

    ...rest of your .cmp file

</aura:component>
```

Comment: setting `<aura:attribute name="panelHeight" type="Integer" default="480"/>` doesnt work. At least, it neither makes the option disappear nor let's you override the value set in `Utility Item Properties`

Comment: I didn't say it would. Answer is about how you can't do what the question is asking - displaying a read-only (emphasis on read-only) property in the utility item properties. The example code was, if it's supposed to be read-only, a workaround with setting it in the attribute within the component (not visible to end user). I hard-coded it, but mention that you can replace the default value with a variable that pulls a value the end-user could actually see that is not editable (custom metadata types, custom settings). If you want it to be editable, then you can use design resources.